# Discern between multiple descendants

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get multiple descendants and give these values to some properties in a class. The part I cannot figure out is how can I figure out between the descendants:

```
var elements =
  from descendant in doc.Descendants().Where(desc => 
    desc.Name == "Name1" || desc.Name == "Name2" ||  desc.Name == "Name3")
  select new AppInfo.Names 
  {
    Name1 = //here I want to get the Name1 descendant .Value
    Name2 = //here I want to get the Name2 descendant .Value
    Name3 = //here I want to get the Name3 descendant .Value
  };
```

Is it possible to do it like this? Or do I have to do a new iteration through the elements?

Comment: I deleted my answer, since it was wrong. Sorry about that!

Comment: no problem, alex. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If AppInfo.Names is simply an array of names, try this:

```
var filterNames = new []{"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
var elements = from descendant in doc.Descendants()
                   .Where(desc =>filterNames.Contains(desc.Name))
                    select descendant.Value;
AppInfo.Names = elements.ToArray();
```

EDIT:

In the case of Names being properties, you could use something like:

```
var names = AppInfo.Names
{
   Name1 = doc.Descendants("Name1").First().Value,
   Name2 = doc.Descendants("Name2").First().Value,
   Name3 = doc.Descendants("Name3").First().Value
}
```

Comment: Name1, Name2 and Name3 are properties.

Comment: filterNames.Contains should get a string as a parameter. I tried to edit, but it seems that someone thought I don't know what I'm saying.

Comment: @naic, if you don't put your entire code here, how are we supposed to help? Also, your tone is rather unappreciative towards people who are trying to help you out.

Comment: SirDemon, I think you got it wrong. I really appreciate the people trying to help. I was just upset because of some edit I did that was not accepted. And still filternames.contains asks for a string parameter, and desc.name is not string.

Comment: it works really smooth now. i hope my edits will be accepted. thanks for your effort!